# how can i detect medicine name and info(use and contents) by using medicine wrappers

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, ocr

I got one project idea creating a Cross-platform react-native app

the project title is creating an app that can detect medicine name and other info from the medicine wrapper

I'm thinking of using Google Cloud Vision to extract all the text from the medicine wrapper.

The text contains medicine mfg info, address, pin code, expiry date, ingredients, and most importantly medicine name.

I want to extract only the medicine names and other info out of it.

What are the possible ways to get medicine name and other info?

and for rural people in India they can't spell the word correctly for that I can give one button that can spell that name for folks can you suggest me any ideas how can I do this and one important part
**how/where can I get medicine wrapper ( Packaging ) of different medicines data????**

Answer (score 2):

- For data, you can search on IEEE Dataport , Kaggle.
- For detecting medicine names and other info trained deep learning models like CNN or you can also perform fine-tuning from the existing model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scispacy. I Think it will suit your purpose.
https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/